# How to disable chosen value in following dropdowns with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

```
function preventDupes( select, index ) {
    var options = select.options,
        len = options.length;
    while( len-- ) {
        options[ len ].disabled = false;
    }
    select.options[ index ].disabled = true;
        if( index === select.selectedIndex ) {
        alert('You\'ve already selected the item "' + select.options[index].text + '".\n\nPlease choose another.');
        this.selectedIndex = 0;
    }

}

var select1 = select = document.getElementById( 'select1' );
var select2 = select = document.getElementById( 'select2' );
var select3 = select = document.getElementById( 'select3' );
var select4 = select = document.getElementById( 'select4' );
var select5 = select = document.getElementById( 'select5' );

select1.onchange = function() {
    preventDupes.call(this, select2, this.selectedIndex );
      preventDupes.call(this, select3, this.selectedIndex );
       preventDupes.call(this, select4, this.selectedIndex );
        preventDupes.call(this, select5, this.selectedIndex );
};

select2.onchange = function() {
    preventDupes.call(this, select1, this.selectedIndex );
      preventDupes.call(this, select3, this.selectedIndex );
       preventDupes.call(this, select4, this.selectedIndex );
        preventDupes.call(this, select5, this.selectedIndex );
};

select3.onchange = function() {
    preventDupes.call(this, select1, this.selectedIndex );
      preventDupes.call(this, select2, this.selectedIndex );
       preventDupes.call(this, select4, this.selectedIndex );
        preventDupes.call(this, select5, this.selectedIndex );
};

select4.onchange = function() {
    preventDupes.call(this, select1, this.selectedIndex );
      preventDupes.call(this, select2, this.selectedIndex );
       preventDupes.call(this, select3, this.selectedIndex );
        preventDupes.call(this, select5, this.selectedIndex );
};

select5.onchange = function() {
    preventDupes.call(this, select1, this.selectedIndex );
      preventDupes.call(this, select2, this.selectedIndex );
       preventDupes.call(this, select3, this.selectedIndex );
        preventDupes.call(this, select4, this.selectedIndex );
};
```

I am trying to disable the dropdown fields that are already chosen but it disables just the last chosen dropdown value.What I want to have is;

When the user first choose accounting then it should be disabled in other 4 dropdown.Then if user selects biology then biology and accounting has to be disabled in other 3 dropdown. Therefore user can set the top five choice

Answer (score 0):

I have [prepared a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wf34fhsz/6/) if you want to take a look at the code in action.

It reduces a lot of the duplication from the `onchange` handlers in the question.

For readability, I have split up the the code into multiple parts:

0) defining the jQuery selector so that one does not have to repeat code:

```
var selects = '#first, #second';
```

1) persisting the selected values inside an array:

```
var selectedValues = [];
```

2) updating the selected values:

```
var updateSelected = function() {
  selectedValues = [];
  jQuery(selects).each(function() {
    selectedValues.push(jQuery(this).val());
  });
}
```

3) Disabling the options that are already selected in one of the selects. The selected option itself is never disabled as that would look weird to the user and would cause the browser to not send the value upon form submit.

```
var disableOptions = function() {
  jQuery(selects).each(function() {
    var select = this;
    $(this).children('option').each(function() {
      if (selectedValues.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1 && $(select).val() != $(this).val()) {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);   
      } else {
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
      }
    });
  });
}
```

4) the onchange handler

```
jQuery(selects).change(function(event) {
  updateSelected();
  disableOptions();
});
```